# Fundamental set of solutions to a differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, fundamental-solution

Say I have a linear 2nd homogeneous ODE of the form $$y''(x)+p(x)y'(x)+q(x)=0$$ Now I know that the general solution to this will be of the form $$y(x)=c_{1}y_{1}(x)+c_{2}y_{2}(x)$$ where $\lbrace y_{1}(x),y_{2}(x)\rbrace$ form a *fundamental set of solutions*.

My question is (and apologies if it is a stupid one), is there only *one* set of fundamental solutions to a given differential equation (of the form above) or are there many?

Would someone be able to enlighten me on which case is true and why? Also, if the latter case is true, please give an example of two different fundamental sets of solutions that satisfy the same linear 2nd homogeneous ODE.

Comment: Think that they form a basis of a vector space.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming we're just considering linear ODEs:

- If it's first-order, we have an essentially unique fundamental solution, in that any nonzero solution is a scalar multiple of any other.
- If it's of higher order, we have infinitely many different fundamental solutions. For the second-order case, this is analogous to how there are infinitely many pairs of vectors $(v_1,v_2)$ whose linear span is $\mathbb{R}^2$

  - For example, consider the second order linear ODE $y''+y=0$.
  - The canonical "fundamental solutions" are $y_1(x)=\cos x, y_2(x)=\sin x$
  - However, if we take $y_1(x)=\cos(x+1), y_2(x)=\sin(x+1)$, we can show that any linear combination of these functions will give a solution (and vice versa, i.e. any solution can be written as such a linear combination)
  - One caveat to this non-uniqueness is that whilst the choice of $y_1,y_2$ can be done in multiple ways, the space of solutions they define is the same. The way we choose them is largely dependent on context.

Comment: Ah ok, so is the point that there are many sets of *basis* solutions, but they will all describe the same general solution $y=c_{1}y_{1}+c_{2}y_{2}$? Is there a way to prove that any solution to such a 2nd order homogeneous ODE will always be of this form? Also, in the example you gave why do we always assume an exponential ansatz, i.e. $y=e^{\lambda x}$, is it simply because it is the easiest solution set to work with (because one obtains the auxiliary equation for the roots $\lambda$ with relative ease)?

Comment: Re: the first point, you seem to get it - it's the same equation you're solving both times, so you're describing the same set of solutions. As for the second point, there's a bit of nuance - with constant-coefficient ODEs, the solutions are (sort of) always sums of exponentials, so it's generally at least worth a try. However, an ODE like $Kx^2y''+y=0$ wouldn't yield any typical exponential solutions - as you can imagine, complicating the equation often means complicating the solution set.

Comment: Ok. Is it possible to prove (without great difficulty) that the solution should always be of the form $y=c_{1}y_{1}+c_{2}y_{2}$ (as opposed to some other form)? Also, in the example you gave, are $\lbrace\cos(x),\sin(x)\rbrace$ and $\lbrace\cos(x+1),\sin(x+1)\rbrace$ really independent fundamental sets of solutions, as you can express one as a linear combination of the other? Or is the point that they both form a basis for the solution set and can therefore (by definition) be expressed in terms of linear combinations of one another?

Comment: Depends a little bit on the conditions you're presented with; if you only know that you have a linear ODE, it's a direct consequence of the "linear"ity that whenever $y_1,y_2$ are solutions, $c_1y_1+c_2y_2$ also are. As for showing all solutions take this form, it's relatively easy to show in specific cases (there's a sort of "factorising" argument you can use which can be quite nice), but a bit tougher in general.

Comment: Ok thanks for the info. Would you be able to comment on the last bit of my previous comment?

Comment: Yeah, the point is that they are different expressions of the same solution space - they represent solutions to the same system. It's like how a line can be described by what happens at $x=0$ - $y=a+bx$ says that it crosses at a height $a$ at a slope $b$ - but you could equally describe it by what happens at $x=1$ - $y=c+d(x-1)$ tells you that it crosses at a height $c$ and a slope $d$. You're still describing the same solution, just in terms of a basis which gives different features more attention.

Comment: Ok great, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4):

There are infinitely many. This is just a basis for your solutions space; similar to the linear algebra, the basis is not unique, but the number of vector in the basis is the same.

Consider
$$
y''-a^2y=0
$$
One fundamental set is
$$
\{e^{at},\, e^{-at}\},
$$
another one
$$
\{\sinh at,\, \cosh at\}.
$$